# not assigning new node to tree when pass into method

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

new node not assigning to a tree when we make it by passing into method but working when made directly, not passing into method.

I have made Node class and MYBinarySearchTree class. when i pass the root node and data in insertIt method then it is giving nullpointerexception in runtime.

```
class Node{
    int data;
    Node left, right;
    Node(int d){
        data = d;
        left = right  = null;
    }
}
class MyBinarySearchTree{
    Node root ;

    MyBinarySearchTree(){
        root = null;
    }

    void insert(int data){
        //root = new Node(data);
        insertIt(root,data);

    }

    static void insertIt(Node node, int data){
        node = new Node(data);

    }

}
class BinarySearchTree{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyBinarySearchTree bst = new MyBinarySearchTree();
        bst.insert(45);
        System.out.println(bst.root.data);

    }
}
```

this above code is not working.

```
    void insert(int data){
        root = new Node(data);
        //insertIt(root,data);

    }

    static void insertIt(Node node, int data){
        node = new Node(data);

    }
```

this above code is working

i don't understand what is difference between the two, because in java objects are pass by reference, so it should give same result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: You change the *reference*, not the object itself. If you pass `null` as `node` and then write `node = ...` the one who passed `null` will not see the newly created value. You should spend more team understanding https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value

Comment: There is a major difference between your code and the code in the link: `insertIt` / `insertRec` is not `void`.

Comment: [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-search-tree-set-1-search-and-insertion/) i am trying to implement this code

Comment: i have not totally implementted insertRec because that was also not working due to the same above problem. that is also giving null pointer exception

Answer (score 1):

This is not really true :

> because in java objects are pass by reference

Java is pass-by-value ONLY. When *node* is passed to the *insertIt()* method, a copy of value of *node* (a reference) is passed. The method *insertIt()* creates another object *new Node(data)* and it has a different reference. It is the variable *node* that changes its reference(to *new Node(data)*), not the object itself.

Here, your function insertIt() should be like that :

```
Node insertIt(int data){
    return new Node(data);
}
```

And in your insert() function :

```
void insert(int data){
    this.root = insertIt(data);
}
```

Furthermore, I don't understand what is the purpose of the insertIt() function, except creating a new Node.

Comment: i was willing to add some more codes in insertIt() method. that was the purpose of insertIt() method

Comment: why not in the insert() one ?

Comment: @criviere because OP is following a tutorial.